# issue on dockerizing the postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    build: .
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: qwerty123456
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres 
      #POSTGRES_DB: sample_db

    volumes:
     - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"


    healthcheck:
      test: exit 0

Dockerfile:
FROM postgres:alpine
ADD ./init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

init.sql:
create database db_sample;

drop table if exists tbl_sample;
create table tbl_sample(s_id serial primary key,samp_name varchar(255))
```

sorry for my bad english

in the above code if comment out the the volumes then it create the database successfully but if if  uncomment the volumes it doesn't create the database in docker container i tried lots couldn't got the solution any body please help me solve this problem

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you running Docker on Linux?

Comment: yes i am using ubuntu operating system